# how to adjust position of selectViewport in radix react-select?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

EXPLANATION OF THE PHOTOS AND CODE BELOW

[image]
[image]
[image]

In the following component (CODE BELOW) I am trying to achieve something like in the screenshot 1 (Where the availableList, the data, is passed from the parent component but it shows an empty space before the data passed) but as soon as I select the data (screenshot 2), and I click again, the drop-down does not show the empty space as I had in the screenshot 1, because I am now in the currentItem -selectItem. By doing what I did in the below code the drop-down is moved up. I am wondering what would be the best strategy to achieve (point 1 in point 3 too) and avoid this movement of the div UP or let it be in place of the actual selection.

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectItemText,
  SelectPortal,
  SelectScrollUpButton,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
  SelectViewport
} from '@radix-ui/react-select';
import { ChevronUpIcon, ChevronDownIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline';

import cn from 'classnames';
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge';

interface BatchSelectorClassNames {
  loadingClassName?: string;
  formButtonClassName?: string;
  selectedItemClassName?: string;
  selectContentClassName?: string;
  selectItemListClassName?: string;
  className?: string;
}
export interface SelectChoice {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

interface Props {
  defaultValue?: string;
  onChange?: (value: string) => void;
  classNames?: BatchSelectorClassNames;
  data: SelectChoice[];
  name?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  value?: string;
}

const Selector: FC<Props> = ({
  defaultValue,
  onChange,
  classNames,
  data,
  name,
  disabled,
  value
}) => {
  const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState<SelectChoice | undefined>(
    undefined
  );
  const [availableList, setAvailableList] = useState<SelectChoice[]>([]);
  const [opened, onOpenChange] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const selectTriggerProps = {
    className: twMerge(
      cn(
        'group flex items-center h-12 select-none rounded-lg bg-white px-4 text-left shadow-plain',
        classNames?.className,
        classNames?.formButtonClassName,
        {
          'group hover:shadow-plain-lg cursor-pointer': !disabled,
          'stroke-inpay-black-haze-700 stroke-1.5 group hover:none text-inpay-black-haze-700':
            disabled
        }
      )
    )
  };

  const selectedItemProps = {
    className: twMerge(
      cn(
        'group flex h-12 cursor-pointer items-center px-4 rounded-t-lg outline-offset-[-1px] hover:bg-inpay-green-200 hover:text-inpay-green-700 border-none focus:outline-none',
        classNames?.className,
        classNames?.selectedItemClassName,
        {
          'px-4': disabled
        }
      )
    )
  };

  const selectItemListProps = {
    className: twMerge(
      cn(
        'group h-12 flex items-center cursor-pointer px-4 outline-offset-[-1px] first:rounded-t-lg last:rounded-b-lg hover:bg-inpay-green-200 hover:text-inpay-green-700 border-none focus:outline-none',
        classNames?.className,
        classNames?.selectItemListClassName
      )
    )
  };

  const selectContentProps = {
    className: twMerge(
      cn(
        'relative z-50 select-none overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white shadow-plain-lg w-72',
        classNames?.selectContentClassName
      )
    )
  };

  const onValueChange = (value: string) => {
    if (data) {
      const matchingValue = data.find((element) => element.value == value);
      if (matchingValue) {
        setCurrentItem({ ...matchingValue });
        setAvailableList(data.filter((i) => i.value != matchingValue.value));
        onChange && onChange(value);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setAvailableList(data);
    setCurrentItem(undefined);
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (defaultValue) {
      const newValue = data.find((i) => i.value === defaultValue);
      if (newValue) {
        setCurrentItem(newValue);
      } else {
        setCurrentItem(newValue);
      }
      setAvailableList(data.filter((i) => i.value != defaultValue));
    }
  }, [defaultValue, data]);

  return (
    <Select
      onValueChange={onValueChange}
      onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
      name={name}
      disabled={disabled}
      defaultValue={defaultValue || ''}
      value={value}
    >
      <SelectTrigger {...selectTriggerProps}>
        <SelectValue />
      </SelectTrigger>
      <SelectPortal>
        <SelectContent {...selectContentProps}>
          <SelectScrollUpButton className="flex justify-center">
            <ChevronUpIcon className="h-10 w-6 stroke-1.5" />
          </SelectScrollUpButton>
          <SelectViewport>
            {currentItem && (
              <div>
                <SelectItem
                  key={null}
                  disabled
                  value=""
                  {...selectItemListProps}
                >
                  <SelectItemText>
                    <div className="flex">
                      <div className="flex-1"></div>
                      {opened ? (
                        <ChevronUpIcon className="w-1/12 stroke-inpay-black-500 stroke-1.5" />
                      ) : (
                        <ChevronDownIcon
                          className={cn(
                            'w-1/12 stroke-inpay-black-haze-700 stroke-1.5',
                            {
                              'w-1/12 stroke-inpay-black-haze-700 stroke-1.5 group-hover:stroke-inpay-black-500':
                                !disabled
                            }
                          )}
                        />
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </SelectItemText>
                </SelectItem>
                <SelectItem
                  key={currentItem.value}
                  value={currentItem.value}
                  {...selectedItemProps}
                >
                  <SelectItemText>
                    <div className="flex">
                      <div className="flex-1">{currentItem.label}</div>
                    </div>
                  </SelectItemText>
                </SelectItem>
              </div>
            )}
            {!currentItem && (
              <SelectItem key={null} disabled value="" {...selectItemListProps}>
                <SelectItemText>
                  <div className="flex">
                    <div className="flex-1"></div>
                    <ChevronDownIcon className="w-1/12 stroke-inpay-black-500 stroke-1.5" />
                  </div>
                </SelectItemText>
              </SelectItem>
            )}
            {/* {opened && (
              <SelectItem key={null} disabled value="" {...selectItemListProps}>
                <SelectItemText>
                  <div className="flex">
                    <div className="flex-1"></div>
                  </div>
                </SelectItemText>
              </SelectItem>
            )} */}
            {availableList.map((item) => (
              <SelectItem
                key={item.value}
                value={item.value}
                {...selectItemListProps}
              >
                <SelectItemText>
                  <div className="flex">
                    <div className="flex-1">{item.label}</div>
                  </div>
                </SelectItemText>
              </SelectItem>
            ))}
          </SelectViewport>
        </SelectContent>
      </SelectPortal>
    </Select>
  );
};

export default Selector;
```